# AES_set_encrypt_key Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, openssl, aes

I am trying to set a key using openssl. This code is generating a segmentation fault. Can someone help?

```
AES_KEY *aes_key;
unsigned char key[] = {
0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07,
0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F,
};
unsigned char iv[] = {
0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07,
0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F,
};

AES_set_encrypt_key(key, 128, aes_key);
```

I'm also getting a compiler error that aes_key may not be initialized, but from other code I've seen, initialization doesn't seem necessary. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a random guess.
Try this:

```
AES_KEY aes_key;
unsigned char key[] = {
0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07,
0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F,
};
unsigned char iv[] = {
0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07,
0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F,
};

AES_set_encrypt_key(key, 128, &aes_key);
```

I have never used OpenSSL but it might be that memory for AES_KEY (I'm guessing it's a struct) needs to be initialized.
You only declared a pointer.

Comment: You could also declare things always passed by pointer as `AES_KEY aes_key[1]`. I find it more convenient.